# How can I safely accept user input that includes iframes from a WYSIWYG editor?

Tags: javascript, node.js, iframe, tinymce

I'm using TinyMCE WYSIWYG editor to allow users to input rich text.

Users are able to paste links to rich media in the editor. The editor automatically detects these and creates an iframe. For example, if you paste a YouTube link, an embedded YouTube video appears. Users can publish the content of the editor as a post, which other users can see.

I'm using DOMPurify to sanitize input. It (rightly) removes any iframes because of XSS concerns. Though I can whitelist iframes, I'm hesitant to do so.

My question is: how can I **safely** accept these iframes and then render them for other users to see/interact with?

Answer (score 3):

Couldn't find any clear and obvious solution online but I think I came up with something decent. Here's how I allow users to submit iframes safely.

First, I just [joi](https://www.npmjs.com/package/joi) validation library to perform some basic validation on the input e.g. is it a string?

Next, I use [DOMPurify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dompurify) to sanitize the html that the user has submitted. Typically, DOMPurify would find and remove all iframes, given their ability to be used maliciously. However, you can add iframes to the whitelist. But, you don't want to allow every iframe attribute. Some can be used by malicious users to execute javascript e.g. "onalert" and "onerror". For my purposes, the only attributes I wanted to allow were "src", "allowfullscreen", and "scrolling". When adding iframes to the DOMPurify whitelist, you also need to explicitly declare which attributes will be allowed too.

```
    req.body.input = DOMPurify.sanitize(req.body.input, { ADD_TAGS: ["iframe"], ADD_ATTR: ['allowfullscreen', 'scrolling'] });
```

Two things to note:

- Be sure to use "ADD_TAGS" rather than "ALLOWED_TAGS". "ADD_TAGS" adds the tag to the existing whitelist. "ALLOWED_TAGS" means that **only** the referenced tag will be allowed.
- I've not explicitly mentioned "src" as an accepted attribute. Not sure why but it just seems to allow it anyway.

Next, for added security I decided to add the [sandbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe#attr-sandbox) attribute to every iframe. This attribute applies extra restrictions to the content in the frame. To do this, I used [cheerio](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cheerio) to easily parse and manipulate the HTML input. Here's how I found every iframe, added the sandbox attribute, and set its value to "allow-same-origin allow-scripts", thus lifting restrictions on those two restrictions. Why did I lift them? Because the content of my iframes (e.g. a YouTube video) needed it to run properly.

```
    let inputCheerio = cheerio.load(req.body.input);
    inputCheerio('iframe').attr('sandbox', 'allow-same-origin allow-scripts');
    req.body.input = inputCheerio.html();
```

Finally, for another layer of added security, I made changes to the [Content Security Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy) (CSP) for pages that would display this content. Specifically, I set the [frame-src](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/frame-src) directive to only allow certain valid sources for iframe content. For example:

```
    res.setHeader("Content-Security-Policy", "frame-src https://youtube.com");
```

Note that the actual CSP would be longer. This is just an example of using the frame-src directive.

I'm not sure if this is the most secure way to achieve what I wanted but it's the best way I could think of at this time. Please feel free to correct me or supplement my answer. Hope someone finds this useful.